# sharepoint webpart - render user control

Tags: web-part

Can someone help me how to render the user control in custom webpart.
I have created a customized visual webpart and need to render user control.

Comment: A visual webpart automatically load user control with it, So the user control would render, What is customized visual webpart?

Comment: @user21081 you have created a custom user controls *.ascx and you want to load it into you visual web part ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in 2010+ when creating a visual webpart its automatic!

you should see within visual studios under your project an ascx file and its corresponding ascx.cs file.... you then also have the webpart that hosts the user control (ascx) and that is a class ending with .cs

in the solution explorer it would look somthing like this:

```
 mywebpart.cs
 myVisualcontrol.ascx
  --myVisualcontrol.ascx.cs
```

witin the .cs you should see it reference the ascx file and adding it in to the controls tree:

```
    private const string _ascxPath = @"~/_CONTROLTEMPLATES/VisualWebPart1/myVisualcontrol.ascx";

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        Control control = Page.LoadControl(_ascxPath);
        Controls.Add(control);
    }
```

in 2007 you needed to make the above yourself ;) including creating the ascx yourself!